# Writing data from Google sheets to Redshift

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, amazon-redshift

I have 400 google sheets each with 6 tabs. They are projects maintained by different analysts. Is there any way I can connect these sheets to Redshift that will not only insert the data but also keep updating Redshift whenever anyone adds any row in a sheet.

I can use apps script but is it the scalable solution for this use case?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Redshift presents itself as PostgreSQL 8.0.2.

So, just search the web for *"Connect Google Sheets to PostgreSQL"*.

Several suggestions will appear, including: [How can I link a Google spreadsheet to PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28699903/174777)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use redshift spectrum instead? Redshift spectrum supports open  csv file format. More info - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-using-spectrum.html