# Query data from Postgresql directly into a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: postgresql, google-docs

Is it possible to somehow directly connect a google spreadsheet to a PostgreSQL database, I know there are tools to do this with Microsoft excel, but  I din't get any result. Neither direct or indirect tools seem to be available.

I wanted to automate a task that involves exporting a query into a CSV and uploading it into Google Drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I link a Google spreadsheet to PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699903/how-can-i-link-a-google-spreadsheet-to-postgresql)